# HTML empty <a> tags whitespace?

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

I'm working on a menu of sorts, and there's link tags for no reason everywhere in the html. I've no idea why.

Menu html looks like this:

```
<div class="play_top"><a href="/match/create"><img src="<?php echo base_url().'assets/img/play_top.png';?>" alt="play"></div>
<div id="navmenu">
    <div id="home"><a href="/"><span>HOME</span></a></div>
    <div id="community"><a href="/"><span>COMMUNITY</span></a></div>
    <div id="aboutus"><a href="/"><span>ABOUT US</span></a></div>
    <div id="play_bottom"><a href="/match/create"><img src="<?php echo base_url().'assets/img/play_bottom.png';?>" alt="play"></div>
    <div id="gameguide"><a href="/"><span>GAME GUIDE</span></a></div>
    <div id="rankings"><a href="/"><span>RANKINGS</span></a></div>
    <div id="media"><a href="/"><span>MEDIA</span></a></div>

</div>
```

That's before it's processed in a website. Anyway, it also looks like that when I look at the source in the browser. Well, there was distorted elements where there shouldn't have been, so I checked it out, and there's extra link tags at some places, taking up the space.
It'd look something like this:

```
<div class="play_top"><a href="/match/create"><img src="<?php echo base_url().'assets/img/play_top.png';?>" alt="play"></div>
<div id="navmenu">
    <div id="home"><a href="/match/create"></a><a href="/"><span>HOME</span></a></div>
    <div id="community"><a href="/"><span>COMMUNITY</span></a></div>
    <div id="aboutus"><a href="/"><span>ABOUT US</span></a></div>
    <div id="play_bottom"><a href="/match/create"><img src="<?php echo base_url().'assets/img/play_bottom.png';?>" alt="play"></div>
    <div id="gameguide"><a href="/match/create"></a><a href="/"><span>GAME GUIDE</span></a></div>
    <div id="rankings"><a href="/"><span>RANKINGS</span></a></div>
    <div id="media"><a href="/"><span>MEDIA</span></a></div>

</div>
```

Of course I can see the pattern, but I have no idea why it repeats.

Comment: might be issue with your html. Your anchors may not have closing tags. So browser closing it and considering the other tag (which you are assuming is closing) is opening

Comment: Of course, that was stupid of me! Thanks..
Can't believe I didn't see it.

Answer (score 1):

You were not closing anchor tags for image links.

Try this

```
<div class="play_top"><a href="/match/create"><img src="<?php echo base_url().'assets/img/play_top.png';?>" alt="play" /></a></div>
<div id="navmenu">
    <div id="home"><a href="/"><span>HOME</span></a></div>
    <div id="community"><a href="/"><span>COMMUNITY</span></a></div>
    <div id="aboutus"><a href="/"><span>ABOUT US</span></a></div>
    <div id="play_bottom"><a href="/match/create"><img src="<?php echo base_url().'assets/img/play_bottom.png';?>" alt="play" /></a></div>
    <div id="gameguide"><a href="/"><span>GAME GUIDE</span></a></div>
    <div id="rankings"><a href="/"><span>RANKINGS</span></a></div>
    <div id="media"><a href="/"><span>MEDIA</span></a></div>

</div>
```

Hope it will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to close the link tags on a few places in the HTML.